# Django Formset adding two rows instead of one with same input id

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I'm trying to implement dynamic formset using django. It is working properly except that it adds two rows of input field with same ID when add button is clicked. ony one row is supposed to be added.

models.py

```
class StaffEmailCC(BaseModel):
    staff_email = models.ForeignKey("projects.StaffEmail",blank=True,null=True)
    cc_addresses=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'staffmailcc'
        verbose_name = _('staffmailcc')
        verbose_name_plural = _('staffmailcc')
        ordering = ('-date_added',)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cc_addresses
```

forms.py

```
class StaffEmailCCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StaffEmailCCForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = StaffEmailCC
        fields = ['cc_addresses']
        widgets = {
            'cc_addresses': autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('StaffAutocomplete'),
        }
```

views.py

```
def create_staff_mail(request):
    StaffEmailCCFormset = formset_factory(StaffEmailCCForm)
    staff_email_cc_formset = StaffEmailCCFormset(prefix='staff_email_cc_formset')
    form = StaffEmailForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "staff_email_cc_formset":staff_email_cc_formset,
        "title": "Create Staff Mail",
        "sender_email":sender_email,
            }
    return render(request, 'projects/create_staff_mail.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<div class="content formElements add_item_container staff_email_cc_formset">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>CC</th>
                </tr>
                {% for i in staff_email_cc_formset.forms %}
                <tr class="form_set_row">
                        <td>
                            <span class="left cc_addresses">
                                {{i.cc_addresses}}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
             </table>
        {{ staff_email_cc_formset.management_form }}
    </div>
```

js

```
$('.staff_email_cc_formset table tr.form_set_row').formset({
                prefix: '{{ staff_email_cc_formset.prefix }}',
                formCssClass: 'dynamic-formset1'
            });
```

Each time i click the add button, two rows are added, out of which only one row working correctly with autocomplete. any idea what i' doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the wrong answer. Did you manage to find a solution? To me it now looks like your `$.(...).formset(...);` might be the issue. Which is not basic django, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem weird. but putting the js function inside $(document).ready(function (){}); solved my issue

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.staff_email_cc_formset table tr.form_set_row').formset({
            prefix: '{{ staff_email_cc_formset.prefix }}',
            formCssClass: 'dynamic-formset1'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Django formsets have `extra=1` as default.

> [...]The number of empty forms that is displayed is controlled by the extra parameter. By default, formset_factory() defines one extra form[...]

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/): search for `extra=` in the page to quickly find what you're looking for.

```py
StaffEmailCCFormset = formset_factory(StaffEmailCCForm, extra=0)
```

Comment: okay it should be StaffEmailCCFormset = formset_factory(StaffEmailCCForm,extra=0). but then again, what it does is set the number of initial rows on pageload. my problem is entirely different. when i'm clicking the add button, two rows are being dynamically generated

Comment: Woops, yes I'll update the answer to show the correct code line. And my bad that I misunderstood your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign fields to formset,

if you write formset like this, it takes extra field default 1:

StaffEmailCCFormset = formset_factory(StaffEmailCCForm)

you overwrite extra field 
StaffEmailCCFormset = formset_factory(StaffEmailCCForm, extra=1)

you can see source code of formset.py
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py

Comment: please read my question carefully. I have already mentioned it in previous answer's comment